# glob exclude alphanumeric mix in gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

**Problem:**
I want to ignore the time directories in openfoam, i.e.

1. foo/1; foo/200
2. foo/153.6546
3. foo/0.5e-05

thus I've added

```
#gitignore
[0-9]*/
[0-9]*.[0-9]*/
```

but this ignores the casefolder as well if it contains any number, i.e. "testCase1D".

**Question:**  Is there a way to exclude arbitrary alphanumeric combinations in the gitignore file so just pure numerical values are ignored?

**My solution approach:**

```
![0-9][a-zA-Z]*/
[0-9]*.[0-9]*e-[0-9][0-9]
```

the former helps with the 1D bit, but parametervariations like foo={"density1000","density1200"} would still be ignored. The latter ignores the "e-" from problem 3 directories.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an asterisk after the numeric value in the first line and adding a second one like so:

```
![0-9]*[a-zA-Z]*/
![a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*/
```

seems to do the trick.